# Binary Tree for Python, getRoot does not return root

Tags: python, class, object, binary-tree

I been looking over this Binary Tree code to figure out what it does:

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    # Insert element e into the binary search tree
    # Return True if the element is inserted successfully 
    def insert(self, e):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = self.createNewNode(e) # Create a new root
        else:
            # Locate the parent node
            parent = None
            current = self.root
            while current != None:
                if e < current.element:
                    parent = current
                    current = current.left
                elif e > current.element:
                    parent = current
                    current = current.right
                else:
                    return False # Duplicate node not inserted

            # Create the new node and attach it to the parent node
            if e < parent.element:
                parent.left = self.createNewNode(e)
            else:
                parent.right = self.createNewNode(e)

        self.size += 1 # Increase tree size
        return True # Element inserted

    # Create a new TreeNode for element e
    def createNewNode(self, e):
        return TreeNode(e)

    # Return the size of the tree
    def getSize(self):
        return self.size

    # Return true if the tree is empty
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.size == 0
        
    # Remove all elements from the tree
    def clear(self):
        self.root == None
        self.size == 0

    # Return the root of the tree
    def getRoot(self):
        return self.root

class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, e):
        self.element = e
        self.left = None  # Point to the left node, default None
        self.right = None # Point to the right node, default None
```

If I do the following code:

```
tree = BinaryTree()
tree.insert("500")
print(tree.getRoot)
print(tree.getRoot())
```

Result:

```
<bound method BinaryTree.getRoot of <__main__.BinaryTree object at 0x036E1E68>>
<__main__.TreeNode object at 0x036FA1F0>
```

I would not get the string "500" back even though its the root. Is there something missing from the getRoot function? I cannot find what is making the function being unable to return the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tree.getRoot` is a method of the `BinaryTree` object.
And `tree.getRoot()` is calling the method and it returns a `TreeNode` object. If you want to get "500", you should get the `element` property of it.

So you can try the following code:

```py
tree = BinaryTree()
tree.insert("500")
print(tree.getRoot().element)
```

which prints

```
500
```

Comment: @dasfoogle Glad to hear that! Then, could you accept my answer if you want? :) You can refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers